# How to create a Multiple date picker for a search form

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I am quite a newbie to MS Access.I am working with a search form in MS Access and I want to create a date picker in which I can select multiple dates which will be an input for a Query that is used to search and display the results from my table for the records that have the selected dates. I did some research on this,however I was unable to find out a feasible solution for my problem.

As I see there are only 2 ways in which this can be done.The first way is  that is using two date pickers one for from date and other for to date and then search for the records between these days which is not very feasible for my scenario as I might want to choose two different dates for example 4th of Jan and 6th of Jan and display results for only those days.

The other method is to use a list box which displays all the dates that are present in the database and choose from that however this is not going to work for me as if I have a very long list of dates such as from 1st Jan to 31st Jan then it would be very time consuming and also I might select a date which I do not want to to search for also in the results.

Could anybody suggest me how can I solve this problem.I am looking for a multiple date picker property in access.Is it possible to achieve this through the form properties? If yes how can it be done? Or is there any other solution for this problem?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Why wouldn't the first approach work for you? Just create two textboxes, give them a date format and enable the picker.  You would enter Jan-4 in the "Begin Date" textbox and Jan-6 in the "End Date" textbox.  If you want to show a single day, you'd enter the same date in both textboxes.

Comment: @DataWriter - The OP stated that he might just want data from Jan-4 and Jan-6, skipping Jan-5.  This is why the first approach wouldn't work.

Comment: and one more Question.Can I have a Form designed where it can show me the Calender object and when I click on a date it Picks that date and then I can later use it in my Query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend creating a temp table consisting of two fields, a Yes/No field and a Date field. Populate the date field (don't name it 'date') with all of the dates from your list of dates. Then on your search form add a subform bound to the temp table. Users would simply check the box next to the desired dates. Then modify your query to include the temp table with a join on the date fields and criteria that the Yes/No field is True (Yes).

Comment: This is a good solution.  I've never heard of a multi-select date picker, the concept is somewhat unique to what an average user wants to do with dates.  Worst-case scenario is that you put the selection list described above on a pop-up form, which you could conceivable filter by year and month to narrow down the list.

Comment: yes that can be done using a list box in my form only right? Or did I miss any thing here that I am not able to get?

Comment: Sure you can do it with a list box, but it is undesirable, per your original post. It is also not user-friendly with a lot of selections. Using a datasheet subform, the user can easily scroll and even filter, checking off the desired dates without worrying about holding down the Ctrl key. If you have a great many dates, you can provide From/To textboxes where user can enter a date range and have only dates in that range appear in the subform. Then they can select from the available dates.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help!I was stuck with this for a long time

Answer (score 2):

Its doubtful youre still looking for this but for anyone else that happens accross this topic I modified an existing datepicker to allow selection of any number of non-contiguous dates, and insert them to a table. I posted it on UtterAccess (A great forum for Access questions). A link to the forum topic is below, but you need to create an account to download the example file.

http://www.utteraccess.com/forum/index.php?showtopic=1738361&st=0#entry2535392

Answer (score 1):

You could combine the two approaches and have

1. Two textboxes to filter for a short date range (say 1 month dates)
2. Show the dates in this date range in a multiselect listbox where the user can select the specific dates they need.